# What is the difference between a "metaphor" and a "simile"?

Tags: word-difference

I often get the two mixed up and confused. If possible please use in a sentence! Thanks!

Comment: You might want to wait for more answers. Also, you need to provide examples, even if confused. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are figures of speech, where a simile is used to draw comparisons, and a metaphor is used to create a concrete representation, or symbol, for something abstract.

For example, "Life is like a dark tunnel," or "Life is as dark as a tunnel," are similes as they use the aforementioned words, and also because these sentences are just drawing comparisons. These sentences are highlighting similarities.

On the other hand, the sentence, "Life is a dark tunnel," would be a metaphor as it is directly making a connection between life and a dark tunnel. What this connection does is that it takes the abstract idea of life and gives it a tangible representation in the form of a dark tunnel.

However the easiest way to tell them apart is that similes use the words "like" or "as", while metaphors make a more direct connection, like above where it just used "is".

Comment: A metaphor is just an image for something. There is nothing concrete about it. And metaphors are not symbols. Symbols are something else....

Answer (score 0):

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simile):

A **simile** is a figure of speech that directly compares two things. **Similes are a form of metaphor** that explicitly use connecting words (such as like, as, so, than, or various verbs such as resemble), though these specific words are not always necessary. While similes are mainly used in forms of poetry that compare the inanimate and the living, there are also terms in which similes and are used for humorous purposes and comparison.